# Missing from Google

Tags: google, google-index, noindex

Recently I noticed our site no longer appeared in Google search results. Our site has be in Google for the last 3 years without any issues.
So far I've check:

- In the Web Master tools it says there are no crawl errors and that we have pages indexed.
- In the Web Master tools I've checked that the robot.txt file is reachable by google and works as expected.
- In the Web Master tools I've test that google can reach our site and then submitted the site to be indexed.
- In a page rank checking tool it says our page rank is N/A.
- I've submitted a check to see if Google banned us, which came back fine.
- I've added a sitemap.xml file. (Although our site content is pretty static)

Our site is: [www.hiveintelligence.com](http://www.hiveintelligence.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using noindex on your pages, see line:97 when viewing the source of your page. See below:

Line 96: `<meta name="description" content="xxxx" />`

***Line 97: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />`***

Line 98: `<meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive" />`